# Is it on-topic to ask "what are some of the reasons the Star Wars prequels are greatly disliked by the older fanbase?"

Tags: discussion, scope

I never understood what's wrong with the prequels, and I'd like to find out.

Comment: I'd go with too broad/primarily opinion based. Pop into chat, and I'm sure we'd all love to vent about it, though.

Comment: Ask this in chat, and *just try* to stop us from providing a litany of reasons.

Comment: The answer is Jar Jar.

Comment: @Richard - Jar Jar should NEVER be an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is an interesting question, it is unfortunately off-topic and I would vote to close. You are asking for a list (lists are generally off-topic) of subjective reasons (subjective questions are also off-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Echoing @Null, @Phantom42 and @Keen; Whilst this isn't an appropriate subject for a site question (too subjective, too broad, too-opinion-based), it would be an **excellent** subject to bring up in the [Mos-Eisley Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) where there are no proscriptive rules about on-topic conversation.

---

Assuming you go the chat route, you might even like to try to create an "event" by getting  people to attend at a specific time to discuss it or, if you have sufficient rep, by creating your own dedicated "*Why do people hate the prequel trilogy*" chatroom (which you can then publicise on Mos Eisley).

I for one would be happy to attend an event or visit your chatroom to explain <s>why I hate Jar Jar</s> what I dislike about the films.

Comment: I'd be happy to attend, but please give us mods some notice - I wouldn't want the discussion to turn tour.

Comment: @Pureferret - I think there will be much swearing and cursing. Perhaps we could institute a five minute rule when people are ranting about Jar Jar.

Comment: Hi Richard! That sounds like a lot of fun! If I went via the event route, what time would you recommend that would be convenient for the people here?

Comment: @Pureferret Noted, I'll definitely give advance notice :)

Comment: That's a good point. I'm usually around between 9PM UTC and 1AM UTC. Perhaps it might be a good idea to set it as an all day event on a Saturday (with a meeting time at perhaps 10PM UTC when most people will be awake).

Comment: Okay, I will do that. I'll wait a day before opening the chat room in case if anyone has suggestions.